# Is it faster to use goto to skip if statement

Tags: c

Is it faster to skip `if` statement if the statement is true? For example:

```
if (a = true) {
  blah blah...
  goto end;
} else {
  blah blah..
}

label: end;
```

Would this code be faster than:

```
if (a = true) {
  blah blah...
} else {
  blah blah..
}
```

Comment: no, don't do that

Comment: Makes no sense at all.

Comment: the compiler would automatically generate code to branch to after the else part.  Also, you should say `if (a)`

Comment: All your else branches are dead, since the expression `a = true` always evaluates as `true`.

Comment: oh ok thanks sorry for the confusion im new to c :)

Comment: [Avoid `goto` like the plague.](https://xkcd.com/292/).

Comment: ok ill try my best

Comment: @RushyPanchal: I wouldn't go that far. Structured, generic programming in C *requires* `goto`, because C does not support multiple exits well, and gotos provide a systematic solution. The alternative is to keep control flow very small and limit branching as much as possible, i.e. by writing lots of very small functions. Although that is generally good style, it's ad-hoc and not systematic.

Comment: I agree with @KerrekSB `goto` can be extremely useful, especially in error handling

Comment: @RushyPanchal this is a tangent (and may belong in chat), but `goto`s have their place in some embedded applications -- it's true that in general-purpose programming they are an unstructured (often anti-)pattern, though.

Comment: It's the only tool in the C toolbox to break out of nested loops. `goto` has its place, and in fact it is used quite often in the C library itself (just look at the `qsort` source, etc..)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would be surprised if any decent compiler didn't emit the same assembler for these two possibilities. Here is a simple C program that compiles and runs:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    if (c == 'y') {
        ++c;
        goto end;
    } else {
        --c;
    }

end:

    putchar(c);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with `gcc -S`, no optimization flags, here is the output:

```
    .file   "goto_skip_41709548.c"
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushq   %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    subq    $16, %rsp
    call    getchar
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    cmpl    $121, -4(%rbp)
    jne .L2
    addl    $1, -4(%rbp)
    jmp .L3
.L2:
    subl    $1, -4(%rbp)
.L3:
    movl    -4(%rbp), %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    putchar
    movl    $10, %edi
    call    putchar
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.9.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.9.4"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The compiler gave the exact same output for the same code with the `goto` removed. Verified with a `diff`:

```
λ> diff w_goto.s wo_goto.s 
1c1
<   .file   "goto_skip_41709548.c"
---
>   .file   "no_goto_skip_41709548.c"
```

Answer (score 5):

When your code compiles, it would probably (i.e. on most decent compilers) translate to something similar to the following pseudo code:

```
    if (a != true)
        jump else

    foo() * will not execute if a is false 
          * because of the `jump else`
    jump end

else:
    bar() * will not execute if a is true 
          * because of the `jump end`

end:
```

where `else` and `end` are labels (try to run it with true and false `a` on paper).

Basically, both snippets will translate to the same compiled version, and your `goto` will have **no effect** on the result because it is included in the branching. At most, it will make your compiler to sweat for another 2 milliseconds to detect and ignore it.

When considering performance, a manual jump that is semi-implicated has not much significance. Breaking loops, non-redeclaration and other programmer-end optimization activities contributes much more.

---

As a note, this branching is how assembly conditions are built, as one stores the logical operation in a register and compare it to check whether to jump or not. A more precise pseudo code would be

```
    cmp a, true /or/ xor a, a   ; 0 if true, 1 if false
    jne else    /or/ jnz else   ; jump if not equal / zero
    foo()
    jmp end    ; jump to
else:
    bar()
end:
```